# PHP echo result

Tags: php, echo

How would i echo the following result on another page. I need it to echo what the user selects.

```
<strong>Return</strong>            
    <select id="Date" name="Date">                      
    <option value="0">--Select date/time--</option>
    <?php  foreach ($return as $return) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $return; ?>"><?php echo $return; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
```

Thanks

Full code of where the user makes a selection. The information they select on this page is what i would like echoed on another page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
        <title>
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="my.js">
        </script>
        <!-- User-generated css -->
        <style>
        </style>
        <!-- User-generated js -->
        <script>
            try {

    $(function() {

    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Your javascript has an error: " + error);
  }
        </script>
     </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Home -->
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <a data-role="button" data-theme="d" href="login.html" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">
                    Back
                </a>
                <a data-role="button" href="index.html" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="d"class="ui-btn-right">
                 Home  
                </a>
                <h3>
                    Book Car
                </h3>
           </div>

           <div data-role="content">
                <h3>
                    Select date/time:
                </h3>
                <br />
<?php
{
    mysql_connect("localhost" , "" , "") or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());

    $query = "SELECT `book_time`, `book_date`, `return_time`, `return_date` FROM `Rental`";

    //executes query on the database
    $result = mysql_query ($query) or die ("didn't query");

    //this selects the results as rows
    $num = mysql_num_rows ($result);    

    $return = array();
    $rent = array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {

        $rent[] = $row['book_date'].' '.$row['book_time'];
        $return[] = $row['return_date'].' '.$row['return_time'];
    }
}
?>      

    <form method="post" action="car.php">
    <strong>Rent out</strong>            
    <select id="Date" name="Date">                      
    <option value="0">--Select date/time--</option>
    <?php  foreach ($rent as $rent) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rent; ?>"><?php echo $rent; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>

    </select>
    <br />

    <strong>Return</strong>            
    <select id="Date" name="Date">                      
    <option value="0">--Select date/time--</option>
    <?php  foreach ($return as $return) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $return; ?>"><?php echo $return; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>


    </select>

                <br />
                <br />

                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Book" />
            </form>

             </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is `$return` set?

Comment: Does `foreach($return as $return)` actually work?

Comment: not sure of the question but as it is part of a form the selected value will be in the $_POST or $_GET array

Comment: Did you forget to surround it by a <form>-Tag?

Comment: @Anther Surprisingly, I think it should. `foreach` operates on the array (actually, a copy of the array), not the variable naming the array. So reusing the variable shouldn't break it. But I wouldn't program like that....

Comment: @Barmar, so should the echo statements given below work?

Comment: @Barmar but at the end of the loop, wouldn't the original $data be changed to $data[last_key]?  I'm actually going to test this out myself but just an interesting experiment for some questionable practices :p.

Comment: You say "on another page". How is that other page related to the page with the select menu? The echo statements below will only work on the form handler for this page.

Comment: @Anther Yes, the `$return` variable will no longer refer to the original array when the loop is done. But the loop still works.

Comment: @Barmar, the other page that i am referring to is at the end of this application just displaying the users selection of dates and times along with other details.

Comment: Do you understand how HTML forms work? You fill in a form, click the Submit button, and it sends the values to the script named in `action="scriptname"`. That second script echo the values as described in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form basics 101:

```
~~~index.php~~~
<form action='the_new_page.php' method='POST'>
  <input type='text' name='first_thing'>
  <input type='hidden' name='some_hidden_guy' value='1'>
  <input type='submit' name='submit_button' value='submit'>
</form>
```

When a user submits the above form, the browser will direct them to `the_new_page.php`, and `the_new_page.php` will know all of the form information.

Forms pass the `name` and the `value`, nothing else for as what you need to know. `id` is PURELY for html purposes, and as a rule in HTML, you are not allowed to have more than one element with the same ID. People usually confusingly name the id of the form field the same as the "name" of the form field, which makes learning what each means pretty difficult.

Thus, after submitting the form it will then go to your second page and then you can do:

```
~~~the_new_page.php~~~
//You can then do
echo $_POST['some_hidden_guy'] //will be 1
echo $_POST['first_thing'] //Will be whatever you inserted into the text box
```

If you want the form to go back to the current page you're on, you simply leave the `action` blank, either as `<form action=''>` or `<form method='POST'>`

Persisting the same information for multiple pages!

Now, this is a very not programmer way to do this, as you should find a way to not have to repeat the same code on ever page.  If you do not, and I'm warning you now.. maintenance of this app will become a nightmare as you'll have to edit every single page every single time you want to add a new field.  On to the example.

Now, say you passed information to car.php and you now want to use it on carplan.php.

```
~~~car.php~~~
    <form action='carplan.php' method='GET or POST, whichever it is you be using using'>
        <input type='hidden' name='Date' value='<?php echo $_GET['date'] ?>'>
        <input type='hidden' name='some_other_thing' value='<?php echo $_GET['some_other_thing'] ?>'>
        <option name='plan_id'>
            <?php foreach($plans as $plan): ?>
                <select value='<?php echo $plan['id'] ?>'><?php echo $plan['name'] ?>'>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </option>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Get That Plan'>
    </form>
```

And finally on carplan.php

```
    ~~~carplan.php~~~
    <form action='the_next_step.php' method='GET or POST, whichever you be using'>
        <input type='hidden' name='Date' value='<?php echo $_GET['date'] ?>'>
        <input type='hidden' name='some_other_thing' value='<?php echo $_GET['some_other_thing'] ?>'>
        <input type='hidden' name='plan_id' value='<?php echo $_GET['plan_id']?>'>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='The next step!'>
    </form>
```

Comment: The problem i have is the form is not passing values on the page after. The results from the user needs to be displayed on a page at the end.

Comment: Change your form `method='GET'`.  It should make it very apparent when and why variables are not passed.  And in `car.php` echo $_GET['Date'].

Comment: that works on car.php. So how would i make that work on another page not car.php.

Comment: That depends on how you save the data.  It looks like you're not going to use the database for user's choices or something similarly complicated, so you'll need to keep passing the information. I'll update my answer with examples.

Answer (score 0):

you can echo this via..

```
echo  $_GET['Date'];
```

**OR**

```
echo $_POST['Date'];
```

**OR**

```
echo $_REQUEST['Date'];
```

Comment: Tried all 3. None of them worked

Comment: The last and one of the first two should work on the page that's named in the `action` attribute of the form.

Comment: The last and first two... that means all of above.

Comment: and it should be `method` set to GET/POST what you meant I guess

Comment: I said "one of the first two" -- `$_GET` if the form uses `method=GET`, `$_POST` if it uses `method=POST`. `$_REQUEST` contains the values in both of them.

Comment: Just updated my question. Could you take a look and check if i have set it up incorrectly which could result in the data not echoing

Comment: @user2236990 you also have the name of "Date" set to two different inputs. Make sure that each of the selects have unique name attributes set on them.

Comment: problem is both select have same name = Date. please change the name and use $_POST with name. it will work

Comment: @SumitBijvani, just tired that aswell. No joy :s