# The readline() function doesn't work in a web browser

Tags: php, browser, readline

Every time I want to run my code, it shows no input. I use Xampp to run this on my browser.

```
<?php 

// For input 
// Hello World 
$a = readline('Enter a string: '); 

// For output 
echo $a;     
?>
```

Comment: are you running this on a commandline or in a browser?

Comment: I believe that would only work in command line console. To do the same in a browser you would have to use $_REQUEST pr $_POST variables and a HTML form. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911860/php-echo-result

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readline.php

Answer (score 1):

This does not work in the browser (readline) and will be skipped. The echo than gives an empty value. (https://www.php.net/readline).

If you want to run it in windows:
c:\path\to\php\php.exe -f myfile.php

This only works when the readline lib is installed (php-readline).